# Access the cross domain single sign-on websites using .net

Tags: c#, .net, http, single-sign-on

Let's say I have two websites that live on separate domains, and they have been authenticated with SSO login. I log into the first website and authenticate, and now I decide to visit the second website using a link visible in 1st website. This link redirect to the second website and no credentials needed. (Note that these websites are developed and hosted by some other company and I don't have access to the source code. I have one login credentials and I am expecting to access the page data of second website)

I want to access the websites using .net code. I have done some work and gone up to accessing the link of first website using HTTP requests and cookies which redirects to the second website. But soon after I clicked the link it open domain 2 in new browser tab and generates new session id as well. It doesn't have any connection with first website cookie. But I can access the data of website 2 when I pass the URL and current session id of website 2 manually.

Is there any security mechanism behind SSO login which can be break through to access the common session Id for both website 1 and website 2?How can I find the connection between two domains when they have two session Ids. I can't post the codes here as it have some privacy information of my client.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  There was SAML request and relay state which were sent to login server from both domains. Even though they are not identical, we have to consider them when access the form data. Also with cookies I had to send pls_login_cookietime specifically from the very first request to last request.

Ex:

var cookie =
new
{
pls_login_cookieTime = Cookietime.CookieValue("pls_login_cookieTime"),
pls_login_SimpleSAMLSessionID = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(login.CookieValue("pls_login_SimpleSAMLSessionID")),
TimeOutCheckID = login.CookieValue("TimeOutCheckID"),
pls_login_SimpleSAMLAuthToken = login.CookieValue("pls_login_SimpleSAMLAuthToken"),
pls_login_rememberme =login.CookieValue("pls_login_rememberme")

Here Cookietime and login are two different url accessing where CookieTime is the initial url and login includes the login server url. Even though login doesn't provide response cookie as pls_login_cookieTime, I had to pass it for final url as request headers.

They were very little confusions. If you use tools like fiddler to check http requests you can understand most of the part how they have manged cookies in multiple domains. Rest is in your hand. You have to think little bit hard and differently. But overall it is not difficult. It is just confused only.